# Format string for NSDateFormatter to produce milliseconds

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdateformatter

Since my date is well formatted now all there is left for me to do is to print milliseconds too.

I already tried `setDateFormat yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss:ms`

That didn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to use 'SS' specifier (with number of S's equal to number of digits you want to get - 3 in your case), e.g.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:SSS"];
```

Comment: well, I have not rejected anything, but any user with enough rep could do that... What was it?

Comment: your syntax is wrong, its yyyy/MM/dd otherwise you'd get year/minute/day

Comment: @Vladimir I would also change the last colon to a period.  So it is ss.SSS

Comment: also check if you want HH vs hh

Comment: WHY IN THE HELL IS THIS SO HARD TO FIND and thanks for the info!

Answer (score 9):

Try this format:

```
"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```