# How to convert string date (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ) to Short Date

Tags: swift3

I have a requirement to convert long String Date to Short Date

**Example:**

long string date : 2017-08-10T07:45:43:395Z  to  Th,10 Aug 2017"

This long string date is base on : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

**Problem:**

I need to convert it to a Date Object and later convert this Date object to a string something like this : " Th,10 Aug 2017"

```
I try this but not working:

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

let DateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-08-10T07:45:43:395Z")

I got nil for DateObj.
```

Please kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: The result is nil because your date format is wrong. *Hint:* The milliseconds.

Comment: I m new to swift. Can show me how to correct my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Apple provides a [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html), with links to the Unicode [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Or just google for "ios dateformatter milliseconds": https://stackoverflow.com/q/5675218/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6456626/1187415.

Comment: Your format is not correct:- `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sssZ"`